# How to tell a common cathode vs a common anode full color led?

Tags: led

Is there a way to visually tell if it has common cathode or a common anode on a full color LED?

Comment: Assuming your talking about a four pin rgb led, I don't think there is a standard other than the second pin in, and longest, being the common one. I may be wrong, hence just a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can see the internal structure you can tell from whether the dies are on a common leadframe or whether the wire bonds go to a common leadframe (possibly it will be 2 of 3).

As to which is which (which you didn't ask), I don't keep that in my skull but it's easy enough to figure out.

Failing that, a battery, resistor and a couple jumper wires will allow you to 'visually' see which way the LEDs swing.

Comment: Honestly I think the easiest way would be the latter part ... just hook it up on a breadboard and test it :)

Comment: @DanielBall Certainly the surest way.